# Why is the html code of width 100% for full bar is not working when I am writing. Forget about that, even the copy paste is not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My basic code is also not working, which I have for DIV tried to extend to full window.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%; position:relative; height:100px; background-color:#F00;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I have tried to do by copy paste, which failed even when I copy pasted.

This is original code, as it should be seen (below)

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PwzBBw

And this is copy paste code, which I have done (below)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJVMeE

Comment: This is caused by default browsers CSS. they usually have some padding, margin and other default values.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by default browsers CSS. They usually have some padding, margin and other default values.

Use some normalize.css or reset.css layer to clear all default values and set them from scratch by yourself.

CSS Layers: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/ Or http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssnormalize/

In your example, there is a difference between original what you copied in normalize library. (SETTINGS -> CSS -> Normalize)

Answer (score 0):

remove the overflow-x: hidden; rule from the html,body selector and your title bar will extend the full width

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLorxr

```
html,body {
/*overflow-x: hidden;*/
```

}